# Upload large files to sitecore media library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sitecore, sitecore-media-library

I have a media centric website that requires us to upload large images, videos to the media library.

I have the default settings for the following settings in web.config.

1. Media.MaxSizeInDatabase (20MB)
2. httpRuntime maxRequestLength

I do not want to increase MaxSizeInDatabase limit on the production server for security reasons.

Also, Media.UploadAsFiles is set to false.

So, my question is - Is there a way to configure sitecore such that if the file being uploaded is less than 20MB, it gets stored in the database and the files larger than 20MB get stored on the file system?

Comment: Just a friendly warning, I've found that Sitecore isn't too happy about very large images, when it tries to rescale them (eg. a 10mb hires image, takes a lot of ram, when it's getting resized). So be sure you are running 64bit and with a lot of memory. Also if the videos are very large, the user will have to downloade them first, as Sitecore doesn't do streaming per default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Martijn says, there is nothing built in to automatically detect this, but if you know that the file is going to be large (or the upload fails due to the large size) then you can manually "force it" to save to file on a per upload basis.

You need to use the Advanced Upload option and select the "Upload as Files" option.

[image: Upload Item Item to disk]

EDIT: If you are able to use YouTube then consider the following modules with nicely/tightly integrated with Sitecore. There are a couple of others ways of achieving the same thing for different providers.

- [YouTube Integration](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/YouTube_Integration.aspx)
- [YouTube Uploader](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/YouTube_Uploader.aspx)

Comment: Thanks guys, that was quite helpful. I am thinking of increasing the maxsizeindatabase to store everything in database, or store all items on the file system. Which method is preferable for large files (say upto 50-60MB) according to you?

Comment: Storing in DB will mean increased size so will mean more to backup, plus more load on the database and more internal traffic since the media will be fetched to disk on first request. Storing to disk however means you do not have the benefit of publishing the media across servers (master to web for example), only the actual media item definition not the physical image/video/file, so you will have to set up some sort of synchronisation between the servers. If it is videos then I would personally host them externally if possible, let YouTube/CDN handle the load and traffic for you.

Comment: Should have added, it also depends on the traffic you are expecting for your site. I would still be tempted to YouTube/CDN videos regardless though.

Comment: If you store your mediaitems on disk, you could also use Webdeploy to sync your media across your frontend-servers after a publish event.

Answer (score 1):

No, not that I know of. At least not automatically. Uploaded files are either stored in the DB or on the filesystem, based on your setting. 
You might want to create an override upload method which could automatically handle this for you or use the manual checkbox in the Advanced Media Upload method as Jammykam says.

Comment: Thanks - Appreciate your help guys.